# Why would OraOLEDB.Oracle GetRecordSet() throw "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" error?

Tags: sql, oracle, vb6, ora-00907

I am unfortunately working on an old VB6 app that is constructing a huge (11902 characters) ad-hoc SQL statement which is then passed to the GetRecordSet() method of my DBConnection.  The app is using the OraOLEDB.Oracle provider.  When the GetRecordSet() method is executed, however, I get the following error:

ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Now I have grabbed the contents of the string that is passed in to the GetRecordSet() function and have thoroughly examined it and there are no missing parens.  Additionally, I am able to execute the select statement in Oracle SQL Developer as well as SQL*Plus, withou difficulty.  So I am sure that the string is syntactically correct.

I am beginning to suspect that something fishy is happening in the provider - perhaps the string is too long and it is getting truncated somewhere?

Can anyone out there help me out?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

Check the oracle trace file.
First set your session in trace mode:
Alter session set sql_trace = true;

And run your query in the same session. You can find the trace file on the database server in the directory pointed to by the user_dump_dest.

If the query is completely in the trace file, it has been completely received by the database.

Comment: thanks for your response.  i am a complete newbie when it comes to Oracle.  where, exactly, do I go to "set my session in trace mode"?  I am assuming that this is something I would do in SQL*Plus.  But if I do this in SQL*Plus, won't that be a different session than that being executed by my VB6 app?  The query seems to run just fine in SQL*Plus.  The problem only seems to occur when attempting to execute the query via the GetRecordSet() function within my app.

Comment: also, absolute Oracle beginner that I am, where can I find the "user_dump_dest" setting?  thanks again, for your help

Comment: select value from v$parameter where name = 'user_dump_dest'; You can also user select name, value from v$parameter to list all instance parameters.

Comment: Steve, adjust the app to execute the 'alter session set sql_trace = true' for you, before it executes your challenging query. It is a very useful way to debug your programs oracle behavior so it makes sense to give it a role in the debugging mode of your app.

Comment: Thanks!  That helped on both counts.  Now, after reviewing the trace, it appears that the entire query is getting through.  The strange thing is that there are several chunks in which all of the whitespace has been stripped out.  Thus, rather than "SELECT ndel.PlantId, ndel.UnitId FROM InspectionData ndel", Oracle is actually receiving "SELECTndel.PlantId,ndel.UnitIdFROMInspectionDatandel".  This is really strange.  The VB code appears to be assembling the string correctly with spaces in all the right places, but the provider seems to be stripping them out for some reason.  Any ideas?

Comment: could there be control characters involved instead of space?

Comment: Thats what I thought at first. Not the case,though.  Just to make sure, I went and retyped all of the spaces. Upon further examination, every case where this is happening is where there is a function getting aliased as a field in the result set. e.g. "SELECT fn firstName, ln lastName, NVL([a bunch of sql]) origReading, NVL([a bunch more sql]) newReading FROM ..." in both of the NVL cases, all of the sql is squeezed together. It is almost as if the provider thinks this is all supposed to be a field name and is trying to squeeze it into a single word. Maybe its not possible to alias a function?

Comment: Try with the aliases between double quotes (")

Comment: The actual alias, or the function?

Comment: In fact, perhaps that is part of the problem - some bits of the sql w/in the function have single quotes (i.e. "DECODE((SELECT id3.CurrRdg FROM inspectionData id3 WHERE id3.insptype='NDE'), NULL, 'Y', 'N') useAsBase,").  In this case, everything with in the DECODE parens gets the whitespace stripped out.  Are you suggesting I wrap the entire DECODE(...) in quotes?

Comment: I know in SQL Server, you can switch the order and put the alias in front of the expression (e.g. "SELECT fn firstName, lastName=ln, useAsBase = DECODE(...), ..."). Can this be done in Oracle? ....  apparently not.  lol

Comment: no, only the alias. Don't send the double quotes for other things than aliases and as part of a literal. Also don't wrap the entire decode in quotes. You might need to escape quotes using quotes. At least, that works for oracle.

Comment: Still no luck.  I've tried wrapping the expression in single quotes (and escaping the single quotes w/in the expression); and I've tried wrapping the alias in single quotes.  I'm about out of ideas.

Comment: Steve, fire the query with tracing enabled using SQL*plus and your app. Compare the received SQL; check for the quoting. I guess you have to make sure that your app sends what the session using SQL*plus showed in the trace file. Literally. Maybe VB is doing funny things with your code ....